# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

i'm trying to study how to make apps for Android.
Following a tutorial made [by Google](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) with my modification i get this error

```
12-26 10:42:23.848: D/dalvikvm(1302): GC_CONCURRENT freed 362K, 15% free 2737K/3216K, paused 70ms+89ms, total 204ms
12-26 10:42:23.898: D/AndroidRuntime(1302): Shutting down VM
12-26 10:42:23.898: W/dalvikvm(1302): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.startactivity/com.example.startactivity.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:    1234)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at com.example.startactivity.DisplayMessageActivity.onCreate(DisplayMessageActivity.java:20)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-26 10:42:23.928: E/AndroidRuntime(1302):     ... 11 more
12-26 10:43:11.418: I/Process(1302): Sending signal. PID: 1302 SIG: 9
```

this is the code of MainActivity

```js
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.startactivity.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);

    EditText edit_nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_nome);
    EditText edit_cognome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_cognome);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("nome", edit_nome.getText().toString());
    bundle.putString("cognome", edit_cognome.getText().toString());

    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, bundle);
    startActivity(intent);


}

}
```

And this is the code of DisplayMessageActivity

```js
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String nome = intent.getBundleExtra("nome").toString();
    String cognome = intent.getBundleExtra("cognome").toString();

    TextView textNome = new TextView(this);
    TextView textCognome = new TextView(this);
    textNome.setTextSize(40);
    textCognome.setTextSize(40);
    textNome.setText(nome);
    textCognome.setText(cognome);

    setContentView(textNome);
    setContentView(textCognome);


}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: the issue is not runtimeexception, it is a simple NPE. look at the line number given, something is null there.

Comment: @ForcelTA have you tried with the posted solution below. That will solve your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling to the `toString` method of the `Bundle` instead of retrieving the string stored on it. In addition, you are trying to get a `Bundle` with a key that is stored into it. Try chaning

```
String nome = intent.getBundleExtra("nome").toString();
String cognome = intent.getBundleExtra("cognome").toString();
```

to

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

if (bundle != null) {
  String nome = bundle.getString("nome");
  String cognome = bundle.getString("cognome");
}
```

Take in consideration that if the intent received is not your, and it comes with no `Bundle`, or a different one, your `nome` and `cognome` strings will be `null`, not empty strings.

Comment: Perfect Works. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The logcat shows the problem at-
com.example.startactivity/com.example.startactivity.DisplayMessageActivity

So, the best guess is the nome and cognome values might be null at the point where you set the text in the texviews in the DisplayMessageActivity

Try adding a debug point at the line with text

```
String nome = intent.getBundleExtra("nome").toString();
```

and see for any null values.

Hope this jelps

Answer (score 0):

Change MainActivity code to

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.startactivity.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);

EditText edit_nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_nome);
EditText edit_cognome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_cognome);

 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("nome", edit_nome.getText().toString());
 bundle.putString("cognome", edit_cognome.getText().toString());

 intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, bundle);
 startActivity(intent);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
return true;
}


}
```

Make sure that entry in manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"></activity>
```